# Cannot show an image from Pinata IPFS in react

Tags: ipfs, nft

I tried to show images from Pinata IPFS in map function but it didn't load images dynamically.

```
myCards.map((element, index) => {
    return (
        <div key={ "card" + index }>
            <h4>{ element.name }</h4>
            <image src={element.pinata_image_path} width="400" height="400" />
        </div>
    )
})
```

So I tried to use `require` function but failed with an error.

```
<image src={require(`${element.ipfs_pin_hash}`) } width="400" height="400" />
```

```
Error: Cannot find module 'https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmYak9CFw4mhAwwuepygj5QXZ1dxgVJdiHAimUC8TXhh4N'
```

How can I show an image from Pinata?

Comment: React won't let you use the require method in your component as it's trying to look for resources on the local disk. Furthermore, from what I know, webpack isn't able to process your images as the module can't require something webpack isn't aware of.